# How to print only the contents of a h:datatable?

Tags: java, jsf, printing

I need to print only the contents of a `h:datatable`. How can I do this?

Comment: need to print(hardcopy) the data, shown in a h:datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS [media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) rules to hide all other content from printing.

E.g.

```
 @media print {
     #header, #footer, #menu { display: none; }
 }
```

You can also put it in its own stylesheet file and reference it using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat simpler example, without the caption bug ;-)

```
<h:dataTable value="#{MyBean.myCollection}" var="item">
<h:column>
             <h:outputText value="#{item}"></h:outputText>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```